# Excel error with match "Unable to get the Match property of the worksheetfunction class"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to match in VBA Excel but I get an error and I can't figure out why... If I enter the same match function in the sheet it works but from VBA.

Here is a snippet that has issues.

```
    Set id_range = table_m.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange
    Dim a As Double
    MsgBox "looking for ID : " + dep_id + " in range " + id_range.Address
    a = WorksheetFunction.Match(dep_id, id_range, 0)
    MsgBox a
```

Message box gives me: [image: Table]

However, I get the infamous error:

> Unable to get the Match property of the worksheetfunction class

If I manually type in an Excel cell `Match(1,$A$7:$A$8,0)` it does work, but VBA doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: I'd suspect either `dep_id` is text, or the data in the cells is.

Comment: Most likely as @Rory said.  Also the remote possibility that `dep_id` isn't the value you think it is - you're using `+` to concatenate rather than `&`.  `1 & 1 = 11` or `1 + 1 =2`.

Comment: Please, try `Dim a As Variant`. What does `MsgBox` show? Is it an error? If so, what format does `dep_id` have, against the format in the matching range? Where from the `dep_id` value is taken?

Comment: Please, also try `Debug.Print TypeName(dep_id), VarType(dep_id)`, then select the cell where the respective ID should be found and create a small testing sub with only a code line: `Debug.Print TypeName(activeCell.Value), VarType(activeCell.Value)`. Aren't there any difference? I have some doubts, in case of match error return...

Comment: dep_id is indeed a string. Is this an issue ? @Rory

Comment: @FaneDuru It doesnt work either. The code throw an error before reaching the second msgbox call

Comment: This shouldn't be possible if you declared `a` as I suggested (changing the existing declaration): `Dim a As Variant`...

Comment: Check the updated thread @FaneDuru

Comment: Please, change `WorksheetFunction.match` with `Application.match`!

Comment: Yes it's an issue if the cells contain actual numbers. You should match on `CLng(dep_id)` instead.

Comment: And try `Dim a As Variant`, as I said. If error (in the message), try `a = Application.Match(CDbl(dep_id), id_range, 0)`. `CDbl`, looking to your initial declaration...

Comment: @Rory Well it's an id text, i used number but i would like to allow character as well like `myId1` as an id. Maybe the use of numbers made it confusing ?

Comment: The 'confusion' comes not from numbers. It comes from **different formats**. This method is searching for identic entities... If you want using strings, too, you should condition the way of variable building. Something like: `If IsNumeric(dep_id) Then dep_id = CDbl(dep_id)`. But how did you declare it? It should be `String` for such an approach. Or `Variant`...

Comment: Ok so i've changed ID's to letters just for test. So now dep_id = "MyId1", and my sheet has ID's "MyId1" and "MyId2". It does work. I dont really get the *different formats* issue. Was is comparing `"1"=1` ?
I have a string of dependency with value "1,2,3" then i split by the `,` and that was my dep_id

Comment: If you format the cells in the sheet as text and reenter any existing numeric data, then your code should work as is. As you note, comparing "1" to 1 doesn't work with match.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that **dep_id** was a String but my range value was formated as General so it was considered **Integer**